# Prometheus HELM installation node exporter CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus

I'm trying to install prometheus I used this command to install prometheus can't figure out what's wrong with it

```
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
```

```
helm install prometheus-operator prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

kubectl get pods

```
prometheus-operator-grafana-9f4766c59-njkcw              3/3     Running            0                9m11s
prometheus-operator-kube-p-operator-bc9c449b4-xfz9m      1/1     Running            0                9m11s
prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics-fcf69f99d-5944k   1/1     Running            0                9m11s
prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-exporter-txd9t       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (3m26s ago)    9m11s
prometheus-prometheus-operator-kube-p-prometheus-0       1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (2m45s ago)    8m53s
```

logs

```
 kl prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-exporter-txd9t
failed to try resolving symlinks in path "/var/log/pods/default_prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-exporter-txd9t_41daa974-ebdf-4814-8d7f-087ba5dec96d/node-exporter/6.log": lstat /var/log/pods/default_prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-exporter-txd9t_41daa974-ebdf-4814-8d7f-087ba5dec96d/node-exporter/6.log: no such file or directory
```

```
kl prometheus-prometheus-operator-kube-p-prometheus-0
ts=2023-06-12T14:13:38.526Z caller=main.go:479 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml)" file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml err="parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml: empty duration string"
```